# C# Task Parallel Library and NHibernate/Spring.NET

Tags: nhibernate, task-parallel-library

I have been using Spring.NET and NHibernate for some years and I am very satisfied. However, I was always playing around with multi threading, Reactive Extensions and eventually Task Parallel Library  which is a great framework. Unfortunately all kind of multithreading approaches fail because of NHiberntate's session which is not thread safe.

I am asking you how can I benefit from parallel programming and still utilising NHibernate.

For instance: I have a `CustomerRegistrationService` class which method `Register` performs several tasks:

```
ICustumer customer = this.CreateCustomerAndAdresses(params);
this.CreateMembership(customer);
this.CreateGeoLookups(customer.Address);
this.SendWelcomeMail(customer);
```

The last two methods would be ideal candidates to run parallel, `CreateGeoLookups` calls some web services to determine geo locations of the customer's address and creates some new entities as well as updates the customer itself. `SendWelcomMail` does what it says.

Because `CreateGeoLookups` does use NHibernate (although through repository objects so NHibernate is acutally hidden via Interfaces/Dependency Inection) it won't work with Task.Factory.StarNew(...) or other Threading mechanisms.

My question is not to solve this very issue I have described but I would like to hear from you about NHibenrate, Spring.NET and parallel approaches.

Thank you very much
Max

Answer (score 8):

In NH its the ISession that isn't thread-safe but the ISessionFactory is entirely thread-safe, easily supporting what it seems you are after.  If you have designed your session-lifecycle-management (and the repositories that depend upon it) such that you assume one single consistent ISession across calls, then, yes, you will have this kind of trouble.  But if you have designed your session-handling pattern to only assume a single ISessionFactory but not to make assumptions about ISession, then there is nothing inherently preventing you from interacting with NH in parallel.

Although you don't specifically mention your use case as being for the web, its important to take note that in web-centric use-cases (e.g., what is a pretty common case for Spring.NET users as well as many other NH-managing-frameworks), the often-used 'Session-Per-Request' pattern of ISession management (often referred to in Spring.NET as 'Open Session In View' or just 'OSIV') will NOT work and you will need to switch to a different duration of your ISession lifecycle.  This is because (as the name suggests) the session-per-request/OSIV pattern makes the (now incorrect in your case) assumption that there is only a single ISession instance for the duration of each HttpRequest (and presumably you would want to be spawning these parallel NH calls all within the context of a single HttpRequest in the web use case).

Obviously in the non-web case where there's rarely a similar concept to session-per-request you wouldn't be as likely to run into this issue as session-lifecycle management is rarely as fine-grained/short-lived as it in web-based applications.

Hope this helps.

-Steve B.

Answer (score 2):

This a difficult thing you ask for. The DTC has to be taken with care.

The only solution i may know is the use of reliable, transactional messaging (e.g. MSMQ + NServiceBus/MassTransit).

Such a design enables you to do this. It would look like this:

```
var customerUid=CreateCustomers(); 
Bus.Publish(new CustomerCreatedEvent() { CustomerUid = customerUid});
```

Then you could use two event handlers (Reactors) that handle the event and send an EMail or create the lookups.

This won´t allow you sharing the Transaction either but will ensure that the Reactors are run (in a new Transaction) when the creation of the customer suceeded.
Also this has nothing to do with the TPL.

Comment: For the problem stated, I actually believe this is the more sensible approach. You wouldn't want to not create the customer because you couldn't create the geographic data, or send an email, rather you'd want to retry both of those processes until they complete. This is a perfect fit for the message queue architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you for answering. I know that the 'ISession that isn't thread-safe but the ISessionFactory is entirely thread-safe'. My problem in the above code for example is that the whole operation is wrapped in one transaction. So this.CreateCustomerAndAdresses(params) on main thread #1 will use for instance ISession #1 with transaction #1. Calling the other three in parallel will create three more threads and three more sessions and transactions which leads to database timeouts in my case. My assumption is that the transaction #1 is not successfully commited because it waits for the three concurrent tasks to complete. But the three concurrent tasks try to read from the database while a transaction is still active leading to deadlocks/timeouts.

So is there some way to tell the other threads/sessions not to create a new transaction but use the main transaction #1?

I am using the TxScopeTransactionManager from Spring.NET which utilises DTC (System.Transactions). I have googled that maybe System.Transactions.DependentTransaction could work but do not have a clue how to integrate it in my Spring.NET transaction managed scenario.

Thanks

Comment: You really should edit your main question with this question.  Did any of these work as an answer?